# How to store VIm session periodically

Tags: vim

In order to be able to restore my current session in case of crash, battery shortage, whatever.. I would like to store my session (`mksession session.vim`) periodically.

I did some research but the only thing I found is these two posts.

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Timer_to_execute_commands_periodically
- https://medium.com/@jooblee/save-your-hundred-of-key-strokes-with-simple-
  timer-in-vim-8-0-feature-8cd4a2457a74

The first one does not really make me happy.

The second did not work for me (I'm using currently vim version 8.0.1839)
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Timer_to_execute_commands_periodically

Here is what I tried with the second link:

```
function SaveSession(timer)                                    
    :mksession! session.vim                                    
endfunction                                                    
let timer = timer_start(2000, 'SaveSession', {'repeat', -1})
```

Comment: May want to look into [obsession.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession) for automatic session handling and [VIM ProSession ](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-prosession).

Answer (score 0):

Actually a typo in the parameter dictionary: `{'repeat': 1}` and it works smoothly.